# Tracking source position of AST nodes in a compiler (ocaml)

Tags: compiler-construction, ocaml, yacc, lex, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm writing a compiler in ocaml, using ocamllex/yacc. Things are going well, but I've a design problem. For each AST node I create, it'd be good to have information about line/character position of that node in the source code. That would be useful for providing error messages to the user later.

Now, I can add some kind of meta type to my nodes:

```
type node = Node1 of ... * meta | Node2 of ... * meta
```

but that seems redundant. Later, when I'm done with verifying the AST, I'll have to write

```
match n with 
| NodeX(..., _) -> ...
```

in every `match` which is a waste of space.

What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: For your next project you should consider [menhir](http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/), a superior alternative to ocamlyacc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way to solve this is to use a record to hold the meta-information and the node expression:

```
type node_exp = Node1 of ... | Node2 of ...
and node = { exp: node_exp; meta: meta }
```

and then:

```
match n.exp with
  | NodeX ... -> ...
```